# converting mp3 to 3gp

Tags: conversion, mp3, media, codec, 3gp

How can I convert mp3 files to 3gp files that use the AMR-WB+ codec?

Comment: You are planning to convert from lossy to lossy - you are loosing quality! Best to get hold of the original uncompressed/modified form then convert straight to 3gp for best possible quality.

Comment: At the very least, choose a higher bitrate on the target format than the mp3 was. That will help minimize the overall quality loss from transcoding.

Comment: I'm planning on converting audio books so quality isn't that big an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think [**XviD4PSP**](http://www.winnydows.com/page.php?2) would be useful.
The [**MediaCoder Audio Edition**](http://mediacoder.sourceforge.net/audio/) might also work, it could be a little tricky to handle.